# Is it possible to apply for loop for commands in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Here's an example. So is it possible to apply for loop for a function or a command in python?
As I'm new to python, that's why I'm facing these kind of issues.

Thanks for the help!!

```py
def fun_1():
    print('fun_1')

def fun_2():
    print('fun_2')

def fun_3():
    print('fun_3')
.
.
.
.
def fun_n():
    print('fun_n')

#something like this to run all the functions
for i in range(1,n+1):
    fun_[i]()
```

Comment: You can put your functions inside a list. `a = [a1, a2, a3, a4]`.

Comment: This pattern is very uncommon, though, so this is most likely a very strange thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can store functions into a list. This is called a jump table.

```
def fun_a():
    print("a")

def fun_b():
    print("b")

def fun_c():
    print("c")

func_list = [fun_a, fun_b, fun_c]

for i in func_list:
    i()
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You already called those function when you created the list. If you remove the for loop, those functions still get called.

Comment: Are you sure that's doing what you intend? For me it prints abc once when func_list is defined and i is None. Did you mean `func_list = [fun_a, fun_b, fun_c]` then i()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval`

```
def a1():
    print('a1')

def a2():
    print('a2')

def a3():
    print('a3')

def a4():
    print('a4')

for i in range(1,5):
    eval('a' + str(i) + '()')
```